# Unable to populate dropdownlist using ajax,json,Boostrap,MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello I am trying to populate Dropdownlist in Boostrap MVC but I am getting error in jquery
Error is Faild to load resource:the server responded with status of 500 (Internal server Error)
in jquery

below is the   script which I wrote

```js
<script>
function BindBasketDD()
{
debugger;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/Home/DisplayFamily",
data: "{}",
datatype: "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
async: false,
success: function (data) {
debugger;
var jsonData = '<option value="' +
0 + '">' + "--Select Basket--" + '</option>';
//$(".ddBasketName").append(jsonData);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
jsonData += '<option value="' + data[i].BasketId + '">' + data[i].BasketName + '</option>';
}
$(".ddBasketName").html(jsonData)
//$.each(data, function (i) {
// var jsonData = '<option value="' +
//data[i].Value + '">' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
// $(".ddBasketName").append(jsonData);
//});
}
});
}
</script>
```

controller

```
' [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayFamily()
    {
        try
        {
            var Json_DispayData = string.Empty;
            OrderModel sdb = new OrderModel();
            DataTable dt = sdb.BindComboBox();


            List<OrderModel.Basket> Bsk = new List<OrderModel.Basket>();
            Bsk = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                   select new OrderModel.Basket()
                   {
                       BasketId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["BasketId"]),
                       BasketName = dr["BasketName"].ToString()

                   }).ToList();
            var res = new SelectList(Bsk, "Basket", "Basket");
             Json_DispayData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
            return Json(new { Json_DispayData, SUCCESS = "SUCCESS" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);



        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }'
```

[image]

Comment: Your exception is not reproducing on my end. Have you debug your API. Just a blank API is giving 200 on my end

Comment: Could you provide some more information like BindComboBox method and Order Model. Also have you tried running the API on Postman or swagger

Comment: I am getting data in  var res in controller

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to this

Second and third parameter of SelectList object referring to value and text field respectively which in you case is `BasketName` and `BasketId`

```
   var res = new SelectList(Bsk, "BasketName", "BasketId");
```

You can also pick text and value field like this

```
   var res = new SelectList(Bsk, nameof(OrderModel.Basket.BasketName), nameof(OrderModel.Basket.BasketId));
```